# using DateTime object inside enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have this enum:

```
public enum TimePeriod
{
    Day = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
    Week = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7),
    Month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1),
    AllTime = DateTime.Now
}
```

but cant do

```
(DateTime)timePeriod
```

how can i get the date given an enum?

Comment: I haven't ever even thought using enum like that. (Un)fortunately it can't be used like that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C#, the default underlying type for an `enum` is `int`, and unfortunately is only support basic data types like `int`, `short`, `uint` and so on. Therefore, storing the `DateTimes` inside an `enum` is not possible in .NET.

You can of course make a static class with static properties that expose the `DateTimes` you need instead of making it like an `enum` like this:

```
public static class TimePeriod
{
  public static DateTime Day{ get{return DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);}},
  public static DateTime Week{ get{return DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);}},
  public static DateTime Month{ get{return DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);}},
  public static DateTime AllTime{ get{return DateTime.Now;}},
}
```

And use it like this:

```
myDateTime = TimePeriod.Month;
```

Comment: I was using this with a url, eg /News/Index/Week/ is there a way i could translate the word "Week" using the static class?

Comment: If you want to get the actual name of the property, you will have to use Reflection to fetch it.

Comment: Would it be possible one way or the other to force an input parameter of one of these values, to make it static typed?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Oyvind's answer. Enums Values have to be constant values and not variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a class, not an enum for this.